# How to save a List<INetFwRule2> on Settings.Default?

Tags: c#

I have a ruleList in my form, I want to save every item in it and load the values when i start the application again.

So I created a new settings tab in Properties -> Settings

Edited Settings.settings file like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="fireWall.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="Location" Type="System.Drawing.Point" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">50, 50</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="FormSize" Type="System.Drawing.Size" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">800, 600</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="FirewallList" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule2&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="myTestDataList" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;System.String&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

and finally I saved my list on FormClosing : `Properties.Settings.Default["FirewallList"] = RuleList;`

However when I try to load my rules from user settings

```
RuleList = Properties.Settings.Default["FirewallList"] as List<INetFwRule2>;
```

I get a null exception error.

My Closing Form :

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

         // saving windows size and location

            Properties.Settings.Default.FormSize = this.Size;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Location = this.Location;

         // saving RuleList

         Properties.Settings.Default["FirewallList"] = RuleList;

         // saving list of random Strings

            Properties.Settings.Default.myTestDataList = new List<String>();

            Properties.Settings.Default.myTestDataList.Add("stack");
            Properties.Settings.Default.myTestDataList.Add("overflow");
            Properties.Settings.Default.myTestDataList.Add(".com");

         // saving all settings

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

PS : Am I doing right saving a list to user settings? Would a custom .txt file for example be suitable for my situation?

Comment: is anything saved? (ie., can you see a serialized version of your list in the `Value` tag of the corresponding setting in the file)? According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx), "Application settings can be stored as any data type that can be serialized to XML or has a TypeConverter that implements ToString/FromString" so if this is true for `List<INetFwRule2>` it should work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that anything else like window size and location, or a list of string can be saved. My problem is that Inetfwrules are not being saved.

Comment: but you wrote that you get a `NullReferenceException` on *load*, so where exactly is the problem? No data present, or not deserializable? Is `INetFwRule2` itself serializable, or does it have a type converter implementing both `ToString` and `FromString`?

Comment: Did you instantiate `RuleList` with the keyword `new` before assigning the value from the settings?

Comment: My problem is that the list is not saved. I have 100 rules in my rulelist.When I try to save them in user setting none gets saved.

Comment: did you make sure using a debugger that the line that assigns the rule list to the default settings, is actually executed and throws no exception, and settings are persisted? could you share more of the settings save code in `Form_Closing`?

Comment: ok I added it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Using settings at runtime. Take a look at [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx):

Access the user setting and assign it a new value, as shown in the following example:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

If you want to persist changes to user settings between application sessions, call the Save method, as shown in the following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: OP states in a comment that the other properties (windows size, ...) are saved all right

Comment: The saved method is being called but its saving anything expect my RuleList

Comment: I didn't see the save code so that's why I posted the link to how to properly use Properties.Settings. He probably has not instantiated his RuleList

Comment: No, my rulelist is instantiated.

Comment: Really? When you step through your code and you get to this line: `Properties.Settings.Default["FirewallList"] = RuleList;`, RuleList is not null?
 Then you save using the method mentioned above? And you get a `NullReferenceException`? I just ran a test and it worked fine for me.

Comment: ok did you test it specifically for INetFwRule2 rules? Because I can save lists of other objects like strings just not firewall rules

Comment: Btw by instantiating the rulelist you mean: private List<INetFwRule2> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule2>(); right?